# Access Angular Model Validation Without A Form

Tags: angularjs, validation

I'm looking to do use some of the validation features in an Angular Directive that I am building up. However, the directive may or may not be inside of a form. Is there a way to access the validation status of a model without trying to access the state of a form?
My template is along the lines of....

```
<select id="{{$id}}key" ng-model="newItem.key" 
    ng-options="key as key.label for key in tableKeys" required>
</select>
<span class="error" ng-show="newItem.key.$error.required">Required!</span>
<input id="{{$id}}value" type="text" ng-model="form.newItem.value" required/>
<span class="error" ng-show="newItem.value.$error.required">Required!</span>
<button ng-click="addItem()">Add Item</button>
```

(Not seeing any validation messages here)

On top of it, I want to addItem to check the state of validation as well

```
$scope.addItem = function(){
    if(<do something to check validation>)
    {
        <do some other thing>
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you want to avoid using the form.xyz.$error attributes for error checking. 
I do not know how to do it using a directive, but I do know how to do it using the controller. 
In that case, you can use the $scope.$watch function on your model.

It would be something like this:-

1.) In your controller,

```
$scope.$watch('newItem.key',function(){
    if( <condition to validate> ==true)
    {
        $scope.selectError ="errorMessage";
    }
});
```

2.) In your HTML

```
<select id="{{$id}}key" ng-model="newItem.key" 
    ng-options="key as key.label for key in tableKeys" required>
</select>
<span class="error" ng-show="selectError">{{selectError}}</span>
```

Note: This is only for the select element. You can bind the text input to a model, and do the same for it as well.

The $scope.$watch function will watch out for any changes to the specified model, and will execute the accompanying code whenever any change occurs.

Comment: Yeah, I was hopeful it would be more directly involved with the built in form validation, but was afraid this would be the answer. I'll test it out, and if what you have works, you get the points.

Comment: Although, the documentation does state that is how you check error attributes (based on the form). Why do you think a user wouldn't use the form's "name" attribute, either in a controller, or in a directive?

Comment: You can definitely use the form's name in a controller. Again, not sure about directive. I thought you wanted to do the error checking without using the form's name. I'm sorry if I misinterpreted.

Comment: Actually, was looking at your note of "My understanding is that you want to avoid using the form.xyz.$error attributes for error checking"
Sorry, not trying to be nit-picky. Just trying to learn.